# Create CSS rule from query string

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, query-string

Get query string

```
var queryString = window.location.search;
```

removes ? from beginning of query string

```
queryString = queryString.substring(1);
```

query string processor

```
var parseQueryString = function( queryString ) {
    var params = {}, queries, temp, i, l;
    // Split into key/value pairs
    queries = queryString.split("&");
    // Convert the array of strings into an object
    for ( i = 0, l = queries.length; i < l; i++ ) {
        temp = queries[i].split('=');
        params[temp[0]] = temp[1];
    }
    return params;
};
```

// query string object

```
var pageParams = parseQueryString(queryString);
```

// CSS variables

```
var target = pageParams.target;
var prop = pageParams.prop;
var value = pageParams.value;
```

// can't get to work -->

```
jQuery(target).css({
    prop : value,
});
```

I want to be able to supply a query like this one "?target=body&prop=display&value=none" and make the whole body disappear or target certain elements by their class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wouldn't be able to use `prop` as a key-variable for the object you're passing to `.css()`.  In this case, it would translate to a literal string `'prop'`.  Instead, you'd have to do something like:

```
jQuery(target).css(prop,value);
```

---

*Note: be careful about that trailing comma in that hash (after `value`).  Some browsers will error at that point.*

Answer (score 0):

In order to create a css object which you can pass to jQuery, I suggest something like this:

```
// Create css obj
var cssObj = {};
cssObj[prop] = value;
```

After this, the code works fine to me. See the full solution here:

http://jsfiddle.net/q97DH/4/

I recommend removing the question mark with a regex - see comment below.

Comment: The reason he is using `substring` is to remove the `?`.  For some reason I think that some browsers do not include the `?`, so his method may not be the safest.  Regardless, you should modify your regex (replace) so that it only removes question marks from the beginning of the string so that no subsequent question marks are removed: `queryString.replace(/^\?/,'');`

Comment: Jepp, I missed that line. I've edited the answer, thx for the hint :-)

Comment: About the regex: I agree, but I didn't use a regex. I just used replace. But still, question marks later in the string, maybe escaped, would be removed too, which could be critical. So let's be precise, I'll alter the fiddle.

Comment: Yeah :) I consider all `replace` to be regex.  I might be wrong, but for some reason I thought that it uses regex under the hood, even when passing it a string as the match pattern.  It's still not a bad idea to check if the first character is a question mark, since I still think some browsers include it, while others exclude it.